# Python TQDM - Get last iteration to retry loop in case of failure

Tags: python, tqdm

Is there a way to get the last iteration, using Python's tqdm module, in case of failure, such as exceptions? I didn't found anything in the documentation or on Google.

I want to get this last iteration so I can start over the loop from the point where the exception occurred (in my case is a timeout error).

I though of something like this:

```
def loop_and_call_external_service(list, start_at=0):
    if start_at > 0:
        # cut the list using start_at index

    for i in tqdm(list):
       call_a_service_that_might_timeout(list.id)

retry_attempts = 0

try:
    loop_and_call_external_service(list, 0)
except SomeService.TimeoutException:
    if retry_attempts <= 3:
        retry_attempts += 1
        last_index = tqdm._last_iteration_pointer
        loop_and_call_external_service(list, last_index)
    else:
        exit()
exception AnythingElse:
    exit()
```

- Not a real code, just so you guys can understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have you experimented with using `try-except` statements? Also some code could help clarify the issue. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: Yes, thanks, my intention is to put the code inside a try-except, I'll update the question to be more clear.